# HTML <a> not working

Tags: php, html, css, anchor

Apologies for the short title.

When I echo a `<a>`-tag via PHP, the link behaves like normal text; it doesn't change the mousepointer, it doesn't go to any given links, but it does follow the CSS rules for `a`. Here's my code:

```
<?php $string = "<content-box id='about'>
        <content-box-title>Welcome,</content-box-title><br/>
        <p>
            text
        </p>
        <p>
            text
        </p>
        <p>" //this string is all on one line in my code, 
             //but for question purposes I aligned them, so it's better readable

    echo substr($string, 0, 952) . '... </p><a href="about.php">More</a></content-box>';
 ?>
```

And my CSS

```
a {
    color: #d60000;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
    color: #d60000;
}
container > content > content-box {
    width: 920px;
    padding: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

It did work before, but suddenly it doesn't anymore. Can anyone figure out what's going on?

Thanks.

EDIT:
This example is supposed to be a 'preview' of what's on another page (that's why I need a 'more' button). I retrieve the raw HTML from another source and then shorten it. By that reason `</p>` and `</content-box>` fall off.

Also `<content-box>` is a custom element, but it acts just lake a normal `<div>` (see comments)

EDIT:

```
<content>
    <?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING);
        $page = new DOMDocument();
        $page->loadHTMLFile('about.php');
        $elm = $page->getElementById('about');

        $faulty_string = $elm->ownerDocument->saveHTML($elm);
        $string = str_replace('Ã¯', 'ï', $faulty_string);

        echo substr($string, 0, 206) . '... </p><a href="about.php">More</a></content-box>';
    ?>
</content>
```

And `#about` on `about.php`

```
<content-box id='about'>
        <content-box-title>Welcome,</content-box-title><br/>
        <p>
            text
        </p>
        <p>
            text
        </p>
        <p>
            text
        </p>
    </content-box>
```

CSS: Same as before.

EDIT:

```
<content-box id="about">
    <content-box-title>Welcome,</content-box-title>
    <br>
    <p> text </p>
    <p> text </p>
    <p> tex... </p>
    <a href="about.php">Lees verder</a>
</content-box>
```

This is from the DOM Explorer from Firefox.

Comment: what exactly is content-box?  I am a bit confused since content-box is not an actual html tag.  also, you appear to be missing a $ before declaring  your string variable.

Comment: does this `"... </p><a href='about.php'>More</a></content-box>"` or this `'... </p><a href=\"about.php\">More</a></content-box>'` work?

Comment: Yeah, I should have pointed that out, sorry. I have a javascript that initializes custom elements, but they just act like `div`s

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen Do you mean if the page exists? If so, it does. Adding those slashes doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Can you post what the "View Source" of the problematic code sample looks like? The behaviour your are describing usually happens when an anchor tag does not have an *href* attribute, because it's either missing, or the code is invalid and browsers cannot interpret it. I'd take a look with "View Source" and with an Inspector also.

Comment: You don't appear to be writing HTML. Browsers only apply the special meaning the `<a>` element has in HTML when they are parsing HTML documents.

Comment: @pentzzsolt Do you mean like a `JSFiddle`?

Comment: @Quentin Technically speaking I am writing in PHP, yes, but I echo valid HTML, so any browser would read HTML

Comment: You should look at the code you are sending to the browser before worrying about the PHP that generates it.

Comment: it works with what you have given us https://jsfiddle.net/f90jkyms/ but we cant see the rest of your output...did you try and inspect the element to see what css is applied, html rendered?

Comment: @David I tried to make a fiddle and it worked there for me, too. I'll edit my question with the exact code.

Comment: Look at your HTML source code. What is missing from there?

Comment: @kojow7 I looked at my code several times and I don't see any missing things. Your question sounds like you know the answer, but you want me to figure it out. If so, I don't know, so please tell me, if you know.

Comment: You should paste the resulting source code in your question so we can look at it.

Comment: the edit doesn't really help much, have you got a link or can you create a jsfiddle with code from view source? its likely as @Arman Ozak suggests there is something in the html in your string variable that is causing this. we could be all day guessing? Btw I don't really know domdocument that well but are you sure it works with custom html elements?

Comment: Slapping the "HTML" from the latest edit in a [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qms408ey/) and clicking the link shows it working fine (and the 404 page being linked to opening)

Comment: @Quentin I see, maybe the problem lays deeper, or it is something we overlook. Also giving it a valid `href` does not work. Maybe the problem is in that I retrieve `#about` from an external page?

Answer (score -3):

A better approach to this would be to store the text of the content-box tag in it's own string, then use substr to shorten it.

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Text</p><p>Text</p>';
$text = substr($text, 0, 952) . '... </p><a href="about.php">More</a>';
$content_box = "<content-box id='about'>
        <content-box-title>Welcome,</content-box-title><br/>
             ".$text.";
        </content-box>";

echo $content_box;
 ?>
```

Comment: `$content-box` doesn't work. Variables can't have dashes in them!

Comment: As said in other answers, your approach wouldn't work for me, as I retrieve my text from another page